# Hand-Eye Calibration without Robot Arm Calibration

Tags: robotic-arm, calibration

I'm trying to do Hand-Eye Robot-Camera calibration.
And I'm using MZ12(NACHI robot) and D435(Intel camera).

But accuracy of the calibration result is so low. Average error of translation moving is about 2mm.

Maybe the reason of it is that I haven't done zero adjustment for absolute position of the robot arm.
I tested absolute position error of the robot. I moved the robot 800mm on X-axis, but teach pendent showed 803mm. I'm not sure it is big error or not. Do you think this error affects to the Hand-Eye  calibration?

To solve the problem, is it necessary to do this calibration (zero adjustment of joints)?

Comment: Hi Soonmyun Jang, can you be more specific about the "low" quality of the calibration?

Comment: @Ben I used AX=XB method for the Hand-Eye calibration. And I calculated translation value of AX-XB, which was about 2mm.